# C++ STL unordered_map problems and doubts

Tags: c++, stl, hashmap, c++11

after some years in Java and C# now I'm back to C++. Of course my programming style is influenced by those languages and I tend to feel the need of a special component that I used massively: the HASH MAP. In STL there is the hash_map, that GCC says it's deprecated and I should use unordered_map. So I turned to it. I confess I'm not sure of the portability of what I am doing as I had to use a compiler switch to turn on the feature -std=c++0x that is of the upcoming standard. Anyway I'm happy with this. As long as I can't get it working since if I put in my class

```
std::unordered_map<unsigned int, baseController*> actionControllers;
```

and in a method:

```
void baseController::attachActionController(unsigned int *actionArr, int len,
        baseController *controller) {
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++){
        actionControllers.insert(actionArr[i], controller);
    }
}
```

it comes out with the usual ieroglyphs saying it can't find the insert around... hints?

Comment: BTW, why not use std::map instead? That would solve your portability problems.

Comment: a map has not the same access time guarantees of an hash map... that's why i'm using it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use:

```
actionControllers[ actionArr[i] ] = controller;
```

this is the operator overloading java owe you for ages :)

Comment: +1: good point. It's worth noting the difference between this and `insert`: if the map already has an entry for the key, then `map[key] = value;` will change the existing value, while `map.insert(make_pair(key,value))` won't (and has a return value to indicate that it failed).

Comment: Furthurmore, `map[key] = v` first creates an entry in the map whith the default value for the type of v, and only then copies the value v into the entry. For complicated types, there may be a difference in performance.

Answer (score 18):

`insert` takes a single argument, which is a key-value pair, of type `std::pair<const key_type, mapped_type>` . So you would use it like this:

```
actionControllers.insert(std::make_pair(actionArr[i], controller));
```

Comment: This is one case where it would be nice if the standard provided an overload to do just that.

Comment: @deft_code: Like.... `unordered_map::emplace`?  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/emplace/ " Two arguments: one for the key, the other for the mapped value."

Answer (score 4):

If you have already decided to use (expreimental and not yet ready) C++0x, then you can use such a syntax to insert a key value pair into an unordered_map:

```
  actionControllers.insert({ actionArr[i], controller });
```

This is supported by gcc 4.4.0

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
actionControllers.insert(std::make_pair(actionArr[i], controller));
```

Answer (score 1):

STL `insert` is usually `map.insert(PAIR(key, value));`. Maybe that is your problem?

PAIR would be `std::unordered_map<unsigned int, baseController*>::value_type`

Comment: whoa dude,  std::make_pair is your friend.

Comment: They're the same thing, so it just boils down to preference. Some people prefer `std::make_pair`, others prefer `typedef`-ing so you can see what you're inserting. There is no other difference between the two (except perhaps the extra function call used for make_pair).

Comment: @laura: If the types don't match exactly, then there's a difference between the typedef and `make_pair`